# What is the C++ operator ->. (arrow dot operator) found in boost documentation?

Tags: c++, boost, operator-keyword

I'm reading boost documentation and see the following at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html :

> Operators that cannot be overloaded
>
> Some operators cannot be overloaded at all (::, ., .*). For some
>   operators, the requirements on return types prevent them to be
>   overloaded to create lambda functors. ***These operators are ->.***, ->,
>   new, new[], delete, delete[] and ?: (the conditional operator).

So what is the operator `->.` ? I tried Google and http://www.symbolhound.com/ but didn't get anything useful, searching on [N3337](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/1997315) gives 1 result that is `->` at the end of a sentence, and Visual Studio 2012 won't compile:

```cpp
class xT {
    bool operator ->. () {} /* fail */
};

std::string* p;
p->.size(); /* fail */

std::auto_ptr<std::string> a;
a->.size(); /* fail */
```

I believe the author intentionally wrote `->.` since `->` and `.` is also included, but what is `->.`, or why it is here?

Comment: Most likely a typo. Probably meant "->*"

Comment: Could be `->*` http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dotstar-vs-arrowstar.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IT seems to be a typo.

In the C++ draft 3690, there is no mention about an operator `->.`.

**It could be the `->*`**:

> **5.5 Pointer-to-member operators [expr.mptr.oper]**
>
> The pointer-to-member operators `->*` and `.*` group left-to-right.

And in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html, they have some example with this operator.

Comment: Well... `.*` is also here but I didn't think about it... My mind was filled with something that calls user-defined `operator ->` and get member from the non-pointer result

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from C++11, 2.13: "Operators and punctuators", there is no such operator as "`->.`".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator like "->."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x04xhy0h.aspx